# unable to connect client to the server programing in different computers

Tags: python, sockets

I am learning socket programing using Python with simple example. But in local PC client able to connect with server. When I want to test same code in two different computers below is the error.

```
File "C:\Python27\lib\socket.py", line 228, in meth
    return getattr(self._sock,name)(*args)
socket.error: [Errno 10060] A connection attempt failed because the connected pa
rty did not properly respond after a period of time, or established connection f
ailed because connected host has failed to respond
```

## Server

```
import socket

s = socket.socket()

print("after socket creation")
s.bind(("",9999))
hostname = socket.gethostname()
IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname)
print("IPAddr: "+IPAddr);
print("listening")
s.listen(5)
while True:
    clt,adr = s.accept()
    print(f"connection to {adr} established")
    clt.send(bytes("info from server", "utf-8"))
```

## client

```
import socket
# host name is output of IPAddr = socket.gethostbyname(hostname) another PC
s = socket.socket()
s.connect((host,9999))
msg = s.recv(100)
print(msg.decode("utf-8"))
```

Please help me to resolve the issue,Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you try to use s.bind(("0.0.0.0",9999)) ip adress in your server? Then try to connect server via its own ip  like 192.168.x.xxx. from client

Comment: There's nothing wrong with the code other than assuming TCP is message-based but that will work for this simple example.  Do you have an active firewall on the host PC?  Are they on the same subnet?

Comment: Client and Server are in same network but server remote connection was disable this could be a problem?